# Not able to recover states after restart apche flink with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-flink, rocksdb

```
             Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.setBoolean("state.backend.local-recovery", true);
            configuration.setString("state.checkpoints.dir", rcokDbStorageLocation);
            configuration.setString("state.checkpoints.num-retained", "20");
            StreamExecutionEnvironment environment = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1, configuration);
            CheckpointConfig checkpointConfig = environment.getCheckpointConfig();
            environment.setRestartStrategy(RestartStrategies.fixedDelayRestart(3, Time.seconds(5)));
            checkpointConfig.enableExternalizedCheckpoints(CheckpointConfig.ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION);
            environment.getConfig().enableObjectReuse();
            environment.enableCheckpointing(5000, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
            environment.setStateBackend((StateBackend)new RocksDBStateBackend(rcokDbStorageLocation).configure(configuration));
            environment.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(configuration);
            FlinkKafkaConsumer011<String> flinkKafkaConsumer2 = createStringConsumerForTopic(Constants.KAFKA_TOPIC_FLINK_LOGIN_FAILED);
            DataStream<String> stringInputStream2 = environment.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer2);

            DataStream<UserLoginRequest> userLoginWithPinRequestDataStream = stringInputStream2.flatMap(new JsonDeserializer<>(UserLoginRequest.class)).returns(UserLoginRequest.class);
            userLoginWithPinRequestDataStream
                    .keyBy(UserLoginRequest::getUser_id)
                    .process(new WrongLoginProcessor())
                    .name(AppConstants.MONITOR_NAME.LOGIN_WITH_PIN);
            environment.execute();
```

This is my configuration at restart of my spring boot application I am not fetch previous states what is the issue here?

for example I had 2 states in the rockdb then after restart those 20 states should be recoverd from the rockdb

Comment: How are you restarting the application?

Comment: I am manually restarting the application or you can say the .jar file of the application

Comment: With this manual restart, are you supplying either a retained checkpoint or a savepoint? Without this, the state will be lost.

Comment: No I am not supplying retained checkpoint or a savepoint, How I am supposed to supply retained checkpoint or savepoint ? Do i need to add any configuration in my code or I need to run it with an argument if so what argument do I need to provide?

Answer (score 0):

By default, each time you a Flink application the job starts without any state. In order to restart an application using state saved from an earlier job, you need to explicitly make that happen by specifying the location of the savepoint (or checkpoint).

Restarting a job from a savepoint (or a retained checkpoint) using the CLI is described [here in docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/cli/#starting-a-job-from-a-savepoint).

An example:

```bash
$ ./bin/flink run \
      --detached \ 
      --fromSavepoint /tmp/flink-savepoints/savepoint-cca7bc-bb1e257f0dab \
      ./examples/streaming/StateMachineExample.jar
```

The same thing can also be done from [the REST API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/rest_api/#jars-jarid-run).

For a more complete tutorial, see [the section in the Flink Operations Playground on upgrading and rescaling a job](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/try-flink/flink-operations-playground/#upgrading--rescaling-a-job).

For more information about which operational tasks can safely be done with a savepoint vs a checkpoint, see [Checkpoints vs Savepoints](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/state/checkpoints_vs_savepoints/).

Comment: Hello david I am not using flink independently, I am using flink with my java application by using flink core, flink java stream, flink kafka connector, flick rockdb etc. So by running the java application it creates a flick cluster by itself. So in this case what do you suggest what should I do to recover the previously stored states.

Comment: That mode of running Flink is not intended to be used for production deployments.

Comment: Hello david, when I run the jar file with the Flink clusture I get the following error 

org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Could not instantiate outputs in order.
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getVertexNonChainedOutputs(StreamConfig.java:559)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.createRecordWriters(StreamTask.java:1618)
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.createRecordWriterDelegate(StreamTask.java:1602)
 

Can You tell me how to overcome this ?

Comment: I've never seen that error. I don't know what can cause it.